# Поиск необходимого файла на компьютерах в сети с использованием Powershell-скрипта

Tags: powershell, скрипт

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться! Что-то у меня не выходит желаемого результата. 
Задача достаточно прозрачная. Необходимо найти определенные файлы (а именно *.pst ) на компьютерах в доменной сети, предварительно проверив доступность компьютера через ком-лет Test-Connection.
Список компьютеров заранее выгружен в текстовый файл - listcomputer.txt, а место поиска локализовано – c:\Users на каждом ПК из списка.
Собрал следующий скрипт:

```
$computers = Get-Content c:\temp\listcomputer.txt
$filePath = "C:\Users\" 
foreach($computer in $computers)
    {
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) 
{
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock 
{Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Include '*.pst, *.ost'} }
    }
```

Скрипт выполняется без вывода каких-либо ошибок, но на экран никаких результатов не выводится. Выполняется примерно 20 – 30 секунд. 
 По отдельности все командлеты выполняются успешно. 
`Test-Connection` – выполнится успешно выдавая результат TRUE,
а
`Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock  {Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Include '*.pst, *.ost'} }`
… то результатом будет вывод наличие либо отсутствие искомого файла.

Вопрос. Что делаю не верно и почему отсутствует результат на экране в полном скрипте?

Заранее благодарен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

пробовал и поиск только по одному критерию '*.pst' либо '*.ost' но вывод вновь пустая строка без сообщений об ошибке

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка здесь - '*.pst, *.ost'. Если хотите искать по нескольким маскам, попробуйте такой код

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -like '*.pst' -or $_.name -like '*.ost'}
```

Правда он будет работать  помедленнее.

И еще переменная $filePath не попадает в блок Invoke-Command. Нужно так:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Include '*.pst'} -ArgumentList $filePath
```

Ну или просто без переменных вбить путь в скрипт напрямую.

Comment: Алексей, уже пробовал ранее только один критерий '*.pst' и результат был тот-же: пустой вывод без сообщений.
Я использовал Вашу строчку кода, но увы... результат точно такой же как и у меня, ... т.е. пустой вывод.

Comment: А почтовые архивы точно есть в профиле? Смотрели просто содержимое папок? Учетка которая запускает скрипт имеет права админа на компьютерах?

Comment: архивы точно есть, специально разместил на пробной группе хостов.
Причем, например, отдельно скрипт: 
'''Invoke-Command -ComputerName Host01 -ScriptBlock 
{Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Include '*.pst'} }''' успешно выполняется, сообщая о наличии и пути к файлу на хосте

Comment: А, я понял! Переменная $filePath не попадает в блок Invoke-Command. Нужно так: ``` Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock 
{Get-ChildItem -Path $filePath -Recurse -Include '*.pst'} -ArgumentList $filePath ```. Ну или просто без переменных вбить путь в скрипт напрямую.

Comment: благодарю! действительно помогло жесткое указание пути в параметре ```-Scriptblock ``` вместо использования $filePath

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю за помощь @AlekseyBokaty 
Итоговое рабочее решение найдено, помогло помогло жесткое указание пути вместо переменной в `-scriptblock`:

````
$filePath = "C:\Users\" 
foreach($computer in $computers)
    {
    if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet) 
    {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users -Recurse -Include '*.pst'} }
    }```
````